# How to add a link to other page in yii framework

Tags: html, yii

I'm beginner to yii framework. I want to make a link to other page.

```
<a href = "contact.php">Click here</a>
```

like this way. This is not working(error page not found). What is the correct way to link using yii framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this guide: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html#hyperlinks this has pointers to creating links in Yii.

Comment: Thank U for answer me.